# Exporting blender file to USDZ?

Tags: export

I wanted to export a blender project with complete animation to USDZ format. Has anyone tried it before? The purpose of it is to use it in an AR application under IOS.

thank you

Comment: One option is gltf and then convert it to USDz: https://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf Another option is: https://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ

Comment: thank you sir!!!

Comment: See: [Is there an USDZ exporter for blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229020/31447)