# Is there any USDZ exporter for Blender?

Tags: animation, armature, export, file-format

I am trying to export to `.usdz`. I am using Blender version 2.92+ and I need to export the model along with its animation and the textures into one single `.usdz` file. However, I couldn't find a plug-in that imports and exports `.usdz` files.

Is there any other file types that can do the same job? Is there any converter to convert my file into `.usdz` format because I need to use it in *Apple's Motion*.

Comment: Does anyone have an update on the issue ? I currently work with Blender to provide animated objects/scenes for AR, on Android and iOs. The only issue is that animations don't work in iOs' AR.
I tried to install ths usd_from_gltf converter, but I kinda got lost in the steps, and honestly I never have done any coding before... Is it really the only solution ?

Answer (score 8):

You can export to a regular [`usd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Scene_Description) file, [`abc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)), [`fbx`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FBX) or [`obj`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) (for static meshes) and use [Reality Converter](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01132020a) which allows to convert any kind of file format to USD**z** (it's just a fancy/simplified GUI for a [python library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) developed by Apple also available on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/)).

[image]

Alternatively you can try [BlenderUSDZ](http://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ) a simple Blender add-on which allows direct export to USDz (limited in functionality though) *or* export to [`gltf`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF) and then [convert the gltf file to USDz using a converter developed by Google](http://github.com/google/usd_from_gltf) if you do not have access to IOS.

Note, all shaders should follow the [Metallic/Roughness](https://substance3d.adobe.com/tutorials/courses/the-pbr-guide-part-2) workflow to ensure interoperability.

Comment: @user126825: Please consider to accept the answer. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Thanks for your support @Chris, appreciated. The user is gone so I don't think this will happen at all. I hope this is going to help future visitors though, it's a valid list of all options we got.

Comment: Tried using the add-on but file size is way small. Doesn't look like the entire model is being exported. Not sure why.

Comment: Try to apply the scale @KDP: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html

Comment: Thank you. I applied scale and tried export, and now I get an Error window. It references the following files: in _init_.py , export_usdz.py , and scene_data.py . I'm pretty inexperienced, but it sounds bad!

Comment: Blender 2.93? @KDP If so, see: https://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ/pull/62

Comment: Thanks @brockmann . Yes, 2.93. So, is it just a matter of waiting for the pull request to be approved, then reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: Just click the [fork](https://github.com/p2or/BlenderUSDZ), download from there, remove the old one and install the provided `io_scene_usdz.zip` via preferences > add-ons > install  @KDP

Comment: @brockmann was able to replace but still getting similar errors. I'm on a PC and see that this plugin is tested on Mac. Guessing that has something to do with it.

Comment: @KDP Works like a charm on IOS, never had the time to test the add-on on linux or windows. I guess the only way getting an usdz file on any other OS for free is using the gltf converter by google.

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal you can run `unzip file.usdz` to extract a folder containing the `.usd` file and a folder of other assets.